# How can I prove that $7+7^2+7^3+...+7^{4n} = 100*a$ (while a is natural number)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

How can I prove that $7+7^2+7^3+...+7^{4n} = 100*a$ (while a is entire number) ?

I thought to calculate $S_{4n}$ according to:
$$ S_{4n} = \frac{7(7^{4n}-1)}{7-1} = \frac{7(7^{4n}-1)}{6} $$

But know, I don't know how to continue for get what that rquired.

I will be happy for help or hint.

---

**After beautiful ideas for solving this question, someone know how to do it with induction too?**

Comment: What is $7^4\mod{100}$?

Comment: @kingW3 the answer is 1, I understand your mind, it's beautiful.  You know maybe how to prove it with induction?

Comment: Notice that $7^5+7^6+7^7+7^8=7^4(7+7^2+7^3+7^4)$

Comment: $S_n = 7(1+7 + 7^2 + 7^3) + 7^5(1+7 + 7^2 + 7^3) + \cdots 7^{4n-3}(1+7+7^2+7^3)$  Now factor out $(1+7 + 7^2 + 7^3)$ and think about the significance of that factor.

Comment: @MasterQuestion:  correct.  Why is that useful?  It essentially solves the problem.  What is $7^{4n}\bmod 100$?

Comment: If you want to use induction, then define $$f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n 7^k$$ $$P(n) = \begin{cases} 7 ~|~ f(n) & \text{ if } n  \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\ 56 ~|~ f(n) & \text{ if }  n \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \\ 99 ~|~ f(n) & \text{ if } n \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \\ 100 ~|~ f(n) &  \text{ if } n \equiv 4 \pmod 4 \end{cases}$$ Then inductive establish $P$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It remains to show that $7^{4n} - 1$ is a multiple of $600$.

Since $600 = (2^3)(3)(5^2)$, the goal is equivalent to showing that the three congruences
\begin{align*}
7^{4n} &\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;2^3)\\[4pt]
7^{4n} &\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
7^{4n} &\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;5^2)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hold for all positive integers $n$.

Now simply note that
\begin{align*}
7 &\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;8)\\[4pt]
7 &\equiv 1\;(\text{mod}\;3)\\[4pt]
7^2 &\equiv -1\;(\text{mod}\;25)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Can you finish it?

For an inductive approach, note that
\begin{align*}
S_{4(n+1)}-S_{4n}
&=
\frac{7(7^{4(n+1)}-1)}{6}-\frac{7(7^{4n}-1)}{6}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{7(7^{4(n+1)}-7^{4n})}{6}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{7^{4n+1}(7^4-1)}{6}
\\[4pt]
&=
\frac{7^{4n+1}(2400)}{6}
\\[4pt]
&=7^{4n+1}(400)
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, if $S_{4n}$ is a multiple of $100$, then so is $S_{4(n+1)}$.

Since $S_{4n}$ is a multiple of $100$ when $n=1$, it follows (by induction on $n$), that $S_{4n}$ is a multiple of $100$, for all positive integers $n$.

Answer (score 3):

$1+7+7^2+7^3=400$, so $$\begin{array}{rcl}7+7^2+7^3+\cdots+7^{4k}&=&(1+7+7^2+7^3)(7+7^5+7^9+\cdots+7^{4k-3})\\&=&100\cdot 4(7+7^5+7^9+\cdots+7^{4k-3})\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

Possibly easier:
$$\eqalign{7+7^2+\cdots+7^{4n}
  &=(7+7^2+7^3+7^4)(1+7^4+\cdots+7^{4n-4})\cr
  &=2800(1+7^4+\cdots+7^{4n-4})\ .\cr}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You have to show $7+7^2+7^3+...+7^{4n}\equiv 0\mod 100$.

Now observe $7^4=49^2=2401\equiv 1\mod 100$, and, as you showed, the sum is
$$7+7^2+7^3+...+7^{4n}=\frac{ 7(7^{4n}-1)}6.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Using the Formula for a Geometric Series**

We need to show more than $7^4\equiv1\pmod{100}$. If that were all we knew, then because $2\mid6$, all we would know would be
$$
\frac{7\left(7^{4n}-1\right)}{6}\equiv0\pmod{50}
$$
However, since $7^4=2401\equiv1\pmod{800}$, we know that
$$
\frac{7\left(7^{4n}-1\right)}{6}\equiv0\pmod{400}
$$

---

**Using Induction**

Note that
$$
7^1+7^2+7^3+7^4=2800\equiv0\pmod{400}
$$
Therefore, if
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(7^{4k+1}+7^{4k+2}+7^{4k+3}+7^{4k+4}\right)\equiv0\pmod{400}
$$
then
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^n\left(7^{4k+1}+7^{4k+2}+7^{4k+3}+7^{4k+4}\right)\\
&=\underbrace{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(7^{4k+1}+7^{4k+2}+7^{4k+3}+7^{4k+4}\right)}_{0\bmod{400}\text{ by inductive hypothesis}}
+7^{4n}\underbrace{\vphantom{\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}}\left(7^1+7^2+7^3+7^4\right)}_{0\bmod{400}}\\[6pt]
&\equiv0\pmod{400}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Induction proof of 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{4n}7^i=100a.$$

For $n=1$, it is true: 
$$7^1+7^2+7^3+7^4=2800=100\cdot 28.$$

Assuming it is true for $n$:, prove for $n+1$:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{4(n+1)}7^i=&\sum_{i=1}^{4n}7^i+7^{4n+1}+7^{4n+2}+7^{4n+3}+7^{4n+4} =\\ &100a+7^{4n+1}+7^{4n+2}+7^{4n+3}+7^{4n+4}
=\\ &100a+7^{4n}(7+7^2+7^3+7^4)=\\ &100a+7^{4n}\cdot 2800=\\ & (a+7^{4n}\cdot 28)\cdot 100= \\ &100\cdot b\end{align}$$

Comment: turned out to be very trivial induction.  (thanks for edit.)  thought might use binomial theorem but didn't even have to.  seems like don't ever need to use that it just sets up the congruence sometimes.